# Char returns weird output C++

Tags: c++, oop, vector, char

I'm trying to do object with primitive character table and STL.

I have searched like 30 stackoverflow questions about same subject, but it didn't give me answers (I think that I'm not capable to read them).

So it works ok when I fill information, but after I try to print them in console, they give weird characters: " ╠ ; ╠ ; ╠ ; ² " I do not know why, this isn't my strongest area, I tried to set char to NULL.

Thank you and I'm so sorry for this stupid question.

My Object.h file:

```
#ifndef Object_H
#define Object_H

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
    private:

    char Name[100];
    char Title[50];
    char Phonenumber[30];
    char RoomNumber[15];

    public:

    //default
    Object();

    //overload 
    Object(char, char, char, char);

    char getName() const;
    char getTitle() const;
    char getPhno() const;
    char getRoomnro() const;

    ~Object();

#endif
```

My Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"

Object::Object(){
    Name[100] = {0};
    Title[50] = { 0 };
    Phonenumber[30] = { 0 };
    RoomNumber[15] = { 0 };
}

Object::Object(char name, char title, char phonenumber, char roomnumber){
    Name[100] = name;
    Title[50] = title;
    Phonenumber[30] = phonenumber;
    RoomNumber[15] = roomnumber;
}

Object::~Object(){
}

//getterit
char Object::getName() const {
    return Name[100];
}

char Object::getTitle() const {
    return Title[50];
}

char Object::getPhno() const {
    return Phonenumber[30];
}

char Object::getRoomnro() const {
    return RoomNumber[15];
}
```

My main.ccp

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Henkilo.h"

using namespace std;

void objectFiller(vector<Object>&); 

void printObject(const vector<Object>&);

int main() {

vector<Object> ObjectList;

    objectFiller(ObjectList);

    printObject(ObjectList);
}

void objectFiller(vector<Object>& newObjectList){
        char name[100];
        char title[50];
        char phonenumber[30];
        char roomnumber[15];

        int size;

        cout << "How many people: "; cin >> size;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "Name: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Title: ";
            cin >> title;
            cout << "Phonenumber: ";
            cin >> phonenumber;
            cout << "Roomnumber: ";
            cin >> roomnumber;

            Object newObject(name[100], title[50], phonenumber[30], roomnumber[15]);

            newObjectList.push_back(newObject);
            cout << endl;
};
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void printObject(const vector<Object>& newObjectList)
    {
        unsigned int size = newObjectList.size();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            cout << newObjectList[i].getName() << " ; " << newObjectList[i].getTitle() << " ; " << newObjectList[i].getPhno() << " ; " << newObjectList[i].getRoomnro() << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Name[100] = name;` ... That can't possibly work? Are you not permitted to use std::string?

Comment: Don't use code snippets for non supported languages please!

Comment: `Object newObject(name[100], title[50], phonenumber[30], roomnumber[15]);` Certainly does no do as you think. This actually passes 1 character that is past the end of each of your char arrays invoking undefined behavior. name[100] is one character past the end of the name array. You are passing that character only not the whole array. Its not even legal to access name[100]. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays to hold strings. They're safer, easier to use, and idiomatic.

Comment: `#include <string>`  You have this included, but you make absolutely no use of `std::string`.  Using `std::string` would solve most, if not all of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is absolutely no reason to use character arrays here.  Your `Object` class is not a simple `struct`, so the reasoning that could have been used, i.e. "my struct needs to be compatible with `C`, so I need to use char arrays" does not apply.

Therefore, use `std::string`, and most of your problems go away.

```
#include <string>
class Object
{
    private:
        std::string Name;
        std::string Title;
        std::string Phonenumber;
        std::string RoomNumber;

    public:
        Object();

    //overload 
        Object(const std::string&, const std::string&, 
               const std::string&, const std::string&);

        std::string getName() const;
        std::string getTitle() const;
        std::string getPhno() const;
        std::string getRoomnro() const;
    };
```

Note that the `Object` constructor takes 4 std::string's by reference.

Then you rewrite your functions using this interface.

```
#include "Object.h"
using namespace std;    
Object::Object(){}

Object::Object(const string& name, const string& title, 
               const string& phonenumber, const string& roomnumber) :
               Name(name), Title(title), Phonenumber(phonenumber), 
               RoomNumber(roomnumber)
 {}
```

Note that the default constructor is empty, since std::string's are empty by default.  The 4 argument constructor merely takes the passed-in strings and initializes the members with the information (note the use of the `initialization list`.

Then we get to your `get...` functions.  The original ones are wrong.  For example:

```
char Object::getName() const {
    return Name[100];
}
```

First, the return type is `char`, which means that a single character, not a string, is returned.  Second, you are returning the character that is located at `Name[100]`, which is incorrect.  Going to position `100` is an out-of-bounds access.

If your goal was to return the array `Name`, you can't return raw arrays like that in C++.  But let's drop all of this and rewrite it correctly, given that we're using `std::string`.

```
std::string Object::getName() const { return Name; }
```

Make the same changes for the other `get...` functions.

Last, your input needs to be changed.  Since `cin` for `std::string` stops at the first whitespace, this will need a rewrite by using `getline`, since `getline` doesn't stop at the first whitespace character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   cout << "Name: ";
   getline(cin, name);
   cout << "Title: ";
   getline(cin, title);
   cout << "Phonenumber: ";
   getline(cin, phonenumber);
   cout << "Roomnumber: ";
   getline(cin, roomnumber);
}
```

That should be most of the changes you will need.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor is wrong, you take 4 characters as arguments and assign them outside the array (valid index for a name[100] is 0..99)

```
Object::Object(char name, char title, char phonenumber, char roomnumber){
    Name[100] = name;
    Title[50] = title;
    Phonenumber[30] = phonenumber;
    RoomNumber[15] = roomnumber;
}
```

if you want to keep the native arrays then you need to copy strings into them

```
Object::Object(char* name, char* title, char* phonenumber, char* roomnumber)
{
    strcpy(Name, name);
    strcpy(Title, title);
    strcpy(Phonenumber, phonenumber);
    strcpy(RoomNumber, roomnumber);
}
```

Now the above solution has still several problems, the sizes for instance, if you declare the arrays as strings it is more flexible.

with

```
std::string Name;
std::string Title;
std::string PhoneNumber;
std::string RoomNumber;
```

the constructor could look like

```
Object::Object(char* name, char* title, char* phonenumber, char* roomnumber)
{
    Name = (name != NULL)?name:"";
    Title = (title != NULL)?title:"";
    Phonenumber = (phonenumber!=NULL)?phonenumber:"";
    RoomNumber = (roomnumber!=NULL)?roomnumber:"";
}
```